# Save in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When working with a model, when do you need to explicitly save?  Say in a setter

```
def name=(n) 
  self.name = n
end
```

Do I need a self.save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, you'd need to do something like this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(n) 
    self.name = n
    save!
  end
end
```

I'd recommend using save! instead of save unless you plan to check for errors since save! will throw an exception but save will fail silently.

BTW, I'm guessing your example was just a quick unrealistic one, since you're overriding the existing ActiveRecord setter function for the "name" field.  ActiveRecord accessor methods are quite different than plain Ruby accessors so if you create "name=" on top of the auto-generated "name=" method, you're screwed.

Comment: +1: AR generates the accessor methods for you from your DB table. No need to override.

Answer (score 2):

Save persists your changes to the database, if you want to persist your changes you have to call save.

In the example you gave you wouldn't call save in the setter, you'd do something like:

```
my_model.name = 'foo'
my_model.save
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything.  You can do a save later if that's what works best for me.

If you're doing many setters for a record, there's no point in doing a save each time.

```
model.foo1 = '1'
model.save

model.foo2 = '2'
model.save

model.foo3 = '3'
model.save
```

Depending on how you're going to use it, you can just do the final save.  As long as you do a save eventually...